# For Loop trying to scrape TripAdvisor Restaurant data

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

I am trying to scrape a list of all the restaurants in Hong Kong and their corresponding URLs. Currently, in my code below, I am able to scrape the 1st and 2nd pages. But I want my for loop towards the bottom to be a bit more dynamic and keep scraping until it hits the amount of entries I specified in range().

I am still a novice at this so any help would be awesome.

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


#scrape the first page because this URL is different then when you start moving to different pages
url0 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
r = requests.get(url0)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
    print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
    print link.string

#loop to move into the next pages. entries are in increments of 30 per page
for i in range(0, 120, 30):
    entries = str(30)
    #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa; hence entries as variable
    url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + entries + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r1 = requests.get(url1)
    data1 = r1.text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
    for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
        print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
        print link.string
    break
```

Comment: Why are you using a range then just using  `entries = str(30)`? You are literally doing the same thing over and over.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got rid of that and placed i in place of the entries variable I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a while that got it to loop the way I wanted it to. Hope this helps people in the future

```
for i in range(30, 120, 30):
    while i <= range:
        i = str(i)
        #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa; hence entries as variable
        url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
        r1 = requests.get(url1)
        data1 = r1.text
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
        for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
            print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            print link.string
        break
```