# Want to know how to crawling at tripadvisor

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, tripadvisor

I am trying to get all of the url links of restaurants in Singapore but my code is not working

```
data = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurants-g294265-Singapore.html").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
    print('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294265-' + link.get('href'))
    print(link.string)
```

It keeps on loading and loading again in the code `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")`

I don't know why this happens even though this works well for other sites.

Is this because trip advisor block crawling or code is wrong?

Comment: I don't see `property_title` on the page

Comment: What do you want to scrape from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It keeps on loading and loading again

To get a response, add the [`user-agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) `header`:

```
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

data = requests.get(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurants-g294265-Singapore.html", headers=headers
).text
```

---

But the data is loaded dynamically, and `requests` doesn't support dynamically loaded pages. However, the is available in JSON format on the website, (It's not clear what you want to scrape). To get all the data you can use the `json`/`re` modules:

```
import json
...

data = requests.get(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurants-g294265-Singapore.html", headers=headers
).text

json_data = re.search(r"window\.__WEB_CONTEXT__=({.*});", data, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)

print(
    # Prints all the data, you can use `json.loads` instead to access  the data instead
    json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
)
```

---

To get all the links:

```
import re
import requests


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

data = requests.get(
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurants-g294265-Singapore.html", headers=headers
).text

for link in re.findall(r'"detailPageUrl":"(.*?)"', data):
    print("https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/" + link)
```

Output (truncated):

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg//Restaurant_Review-g294265-d1145149-Reviews-Grand_Shanghai_Restaurant-Singapore.html
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg//Restaurant_Review-g294265-d1193730-Reviews-Entre_Nous_creperie-Singapore.html
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg//Restaurant_Review-g294265-d1173583-Reviews-The_Courtyard-Singapore.html
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg//Restaurant_Review-g294265-d4611806-Reviews-NOX_Dine_in_the_Dark-Singapore.html
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg//Restaurant_Review-g294265-d13152787-Reviews-Positano_Risto-Singapore.html
```

Comment: What I want to obtain from trip advisor are the links of restaurants in Singapore, for example "https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurant_Review-g294265-d1145149-Reviews-Grand_Shanghai_Restaurant-Singapore.html"

Comment: My main purpose is to crawl all of info of restaurants in Singapore to study python, I only succeeded to get info of one restaurant not all. That is the reason why I search how to get url of restaurants, and list into array then crawl those

Comment: What I referred is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922317/for-loop-trying-to-scrape-tripadvisor-restaurant-data"

Comment: @ChoiJaeWon I've edited my answer to get all the links

Comment: thank you so much, can I ask something more? I just wonder how long does it take to get outputs. For mine, I was over 10mins

Comment: @ChoiJaeWon Did you add the `headers`? with them it should work immediately. It's probably due to slow internet

Comment: Oh there was a blank between quotation marks! It really was helpful to my study. Have a nice day!